# Webpack loader syntax - array with query

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

Extending from the syntax generated by angular-cli using extract I came in the situation of using multiple loaders where one of the loaders needed a query string.

Using the array syntax and adding the query like

```
// ...
{
    "test":   /\.pug$/,
    "loader":  ['raw-loader', 'pug-html-loader'],
    "query":  { doctype: "html",  plugins:  ["pug-plugin-ng"] }

},
// ...
```

did not work (which makes sense as webpack cannot know which loader should use the query.

---

However out of curiosity I fooled around and tried to rewrite the config so that it would be clearly paired like

```
{
    "test":   /\.pug$/,
    "loader":  [
        'raw-loader',  
        {
            "loader":   'pug-html-loader',
            "query":  {  doctype:   "html",  plugins:  ["pug-plugin-ng"] }
        }
    ]
},
```

without ever expecting it to work. **But to my astonishment it did!**

---

When trying to find some documentation on this syntax I found that the proper way to do it was

```
{
    "test":   /\.pug$/,
    use:  [
        'raw-loader',  
        {
            "loader":   'pug-html-loader',
            "options":  {  doctype:   "html",  plugins:  ["pug-plugin-ng"] }
        }
    ]
},
```

according to the [official docs](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#via-webpack-config-js).

---

---

**Now to the actual question:** Why does the second syntax work? I cannot find anything in the docs explaining it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack currently accepts both ways for backwards compatibility.
It seems we can currently mix and match stuff, but it might fail sometime in the future.

See https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#module-loaders-is-now-module-rules